# How to enable HW acceleration in Celluloid video player in Linux Mint 20?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, video

I have this graphics card in my Dell laptop:

[GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit): [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/), [GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1060/), [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/max-q/), 6 GB [GDDR5/X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR5_SDRAM) [VRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_RAM_(dual-ported_DRAM))

which has the basic specification as follows, and should be capable of handling hardware decoding of a high-resolution video (I hope):

[image: GeForce GTX 1060 specs]

---

I really like the simplicity of my current video player: [Celluloid](https://celluloid-player.github.io/), but in [Linux Mint 20.0](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=281) **it does not use hardware acceleration by default**.

This is highly annoying, and also I think a CPU waste, the fan goes to a loud mode while playing a **60GiB 4K (UHD) MKV movie** as an example, CPU while playing this one:

[image: 60GiB 4K (UHD) MKV movie playback]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Celluloid](https://celluloid-player.github.io/) I found, is based on MPV, thus I found relevant HW acceleration options [on MPV help](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-hwdec). I read `nvdec` and `nvdec-copy` options both seem relevant, but it actually can auto-detect the `nvdec-copy` when in [Celluloid](https://celluloid-player.github.io/) GUI preferences you put this line:

```
hwdec=auto-safe
```

---

[image: Celluloid hwdec=auto-safe]

---

After this adjustment, my CPU cooler fan got a lot easier on ears, as proven by CPU usage:

[image: CPU usage with Nvidia HW acceleration turned on]

---

Credits:

*Hardware Video Acceleration* section of Linux Mint [official blog article](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3969).

---

**Check for HW acceleration from inside the Celluloid player:**

You can press <kbd>i</kbd> while playing to confirm what acceleration got enabled if any.